# SolidJS: Typescript error says value is of type 'undefined' despite checking that it isn't

Tags: solid-js

I have some SolidJS code like:

```
{value() !== undefined && <img src={srcs[value()]} />}
```

where `value` is a signal. I get a TypeScript error under `value()` saying `Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)`

What does this mean and how do I fix this without `// @ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typescript has no way of knowing that `value()` returns the same result each time it's called. You can use non-null assertion operator for the second `value()`

```js
{value() !== undefined && <img src={srcs[value()!]} />}
```

or you can use [`<Show>`](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#%3Cshow%3E) with callback. `Show` will pass the value of `when`, if it's showing, to the callback, and its type will be non-nullable:

```js
<Show when={value()}>{value => <img src={srcs[value]} />}</Show>
```