# How to use SolidJS's <Show> tag with Typescript

Tags: javascript, jsx, show, solid-js

I have the following code inside a SolidJS component

```
<Show when={props.hint}>
   <HintText>{props.hint}</HintText>
</Show>
```

It works as expected, however, typescript keeps saying that rather than a *string* `props.hint` could also be *undefined*.

I visited the docs at https://www.solidjs.com/guides/typescript, tried using the "bang [ ! ]" operator (AKA non-null assertion operator), tried using a function inside the  block, but typescript keeps complaining.

*Image for reference:

[image]

Is there a better approach for that?

Comment: have you tried optional chaining? `props?.hint`

Comment: yep...didn't work

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873219/solidjs-typescript-error-says-value-is-of-type-undefined-despite-checking-tha

Answer (score 2):

*indevsmiles* are right about typing of the component props.

However if the variable could be undefined, you could use the keyed-attribute of Show. This will return a NonNullable object.

```
const [something, setSomething] = createSignal<string | undefined>();

<Show when={something()} keyed>{(variable) =>
   <b>{variable}</b>
}
</Show>
```

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#show

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined what the prop argument looks like? If not, then that may be the issue. Below I have an example of what it might look like:

```js
const Hint: Component<{hint: string}> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Show when={props.hint}>
      <p>{props.hint}</p>
    </Show>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ugly but this should do the trick with the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing):

```
<Show when={props?.hint}>
  <HintText>{props?.hint ?? ''}</HintText>
</Show>
```